# Updating a choropleth map with a dropdown button

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

First, please excuse my poor english.
I'm working on a project with a grid-map and an external csv.

The grid-map is not composed of rectangles or hexagons but only with the centroid of any kind of symbol that will be use at the end.
So I have a Topojson file with centroids "ID" and centroids "Coordinates".

The external CSV is composed of several columns, the first one with the same centroids "ID" and the other one with value for different year.

```
"ID","C2001","C2002","C2003","C2004","C2005","C2006","C2007","C2008","C2009","C2010","C2000"
6050,"-5.55753","-5.55914","-5.75444","-5.76307","-5.81660","-5.99361","-6.02150","-6.15979","-5.73530","-6.30509","-5.52990"
6051,"-5.55753","-5.55914","-5.75444","-5.76307","-5.81660","-5.99361","-6.02150","-6.15979","-5.73530","-6.30509","-5.52990"
```

Here is my code

```
var width = 960,
    height = 600;

var options = [
    {date: "2000", selected: "+d.C2000"},
    {date: "2001", selected: "+d.C2001"},
    {date: "2002", selected: "+d.C2002"},
    {date: "2003", selected: "+d.C2003"},
    {date: "2004", selected: "+d.C2004"},
    {date: "2005", selected: "+d.C2005"},
    {date: "2006", selected: "+d.C2006"},
    {date: "2007", selected: "+d.C2007"},
    {date: "2008", selected: "+d.C2008"},
    {date: "2009", selected: "+d.C2009"},
    {date: "2010", selected: "+d.C2010"},
];


var color = d3.scale.threshold()
    .domain([-1985, -1400, -1000, -700, -300, -100, -25, -0])
    .range(["#7f0000", "#b30000", "#d7301f", "#ef6548", "#fc8d59", "#fdbb84", "#fdd49e", "#fee8c8", "#fff7ec"]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(null)
    .pointRadius(1.5);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "CO2_light.json")
    .defer(d3.csv, "tdd_CO2_emissions.csv")
    .await(ready);

function ready(error, centroid, CO2) {

    var rateById = {};

    console.log(rateById); //To 

    //CO2.forEach(function(d) { rateById[+d.ID] = +d.C2000; });  WORKING FINE = value in rateById
    CO2.forEach(function(d) { rateById[+d.ID] = options[0].selected; }); //NOT WORKING = inside rateById "+d.C2000" instead the value

    svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(centroid, centroid.objects.CENTROID).features)
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "centerGrid")
        .attr("d", path)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(rateById[+d.properties.ID]); });

    d3.select(".loading").remove();
```

For the moment I leave the button for my next problem and I'm focus on this two line below

```
//CO2.forEach(function(d) { rateById[+d.ID] = +d.C2000; });  WORKING FINE = value in rateById
CO2.forEach(function(d) { rateById[+d.ID] = options[0].selected; }); //NOT WORKING = inside rateById "+d.C2000" instead the value
```

If I use the first line I get a nice grid-map ([see image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-cz0bhq9RnhQWNYdXVlMHUwQnM/view?usp=sharing)) but if I'm trying to access at value of a specific year from the `options` array with the second line and do `console.log(rateById);` I get this

```
Object
6050: "+d.C2000"
6051: "+d.C2000"
6712: "+d.C2000"
```

Instead of this

```
Object
6050: -6.30509
6051: -6.30509
6712: -7.0441
```

Comment: `rateById[+d.ID] = options[0].selected;` just does what you're asking it to do. The value of options[0].selected is "+d.C2000". You want to lookup the CO2 file's value instead, for this you need to properly format the csv file data (in an object, in order to be able to access the values based on year and centroid Id). Would you mind creating a jsfiddle to make it easier to help you?

Comment: There it is : [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/z7sLdyu2/1/) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/z7sLdyu2/2/

2 changes to do in your code:

First, your options select should not contain javascript code to be executed (`+d.`), but only the year values:

```
var options = [
  {date: "2000", selected: "C2000"},
  {date: "2001", selected: "C2001"},
  {date: "2002", selected: "C2002"},
  {date: "2003", selected: "C2003"},
  {date: "2004", selected: "C2004"},
  {date: "2005", selected: "C2005"},
  {date: "2006", selected: "C2006"},
  {date: "2007", selected: "C2007"},
  {date: "2008", selected: "C2008"},
  {date: "2009", selected: "C2009"},
  {date: "2010", selected: "C2010"}
];
```

Then in the loop, assign the `rateById` value by accessing the data `d` property for the selected year like this:

`rateById[+d.ID] = +d[options[0].selected];`

P.S.: I had to remove part of your code in your jsfiddle, as the centroids json was not found in your version of the jsfiddle, leading to errors not related to the problem of this question.

Comment: Is the plus sign in +d.ID necessary in the rateById function? The .ID values are non-integer.

Comment: You don't need the +sign for the Ids, you can just get rid of it.

Comment: You answered so fast that I can't be there at this moment. It's working like a charm! _Merci beaucoup !_ (in french)